# how do i convert OTF to TTF so that subpixel rendering (anti-aliasing) is ON?

Tags: truetype, opentype, subpixel

okay.  according to @fontface, OpenType PS does NOT have subpixel rendering when converted and used on Windows platforms.  Crap Factor = 9.  my question is, since it's cakey-pants to convert OpenType PS to OpenType TT, what happens to subpixel rendering?  i've tried using some online converters and see ZERO difference: fonts look like crap.

so the question is HOW can i convert an OpenType PS file to an OpenType TT file WITH subpixel rendering coming along for the ride?

because once i have an OpenType TT file, i can get to EOT easily.

thanks!

WR!

Comment: for those curious, follow [this link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/02/the-font-face-rule-revisited-and-useful-tricks/) to SmashingMagazine's article on @fontface type use and scroll to the OpenType section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay.  here's what i've figured out and it works.  but, i can't verify that it'll work with the freeware FontStudio, but it should.  i just didn't feel like installing cygwin to verify that it would for sure...  meh.

i use FontLab Studio, but any font authoring tool should do the job.  Simply open the PS version of the font.  convert the PS paths to TT paths.  this may take a minute or two, depending on font complexity.  Once it's complete, generate a new TrueType font.  convert this to EOT and you're away to the races.

TWO important notes:

1) if you are using an IDE like Dreamweaver or Aptana, the preview will NOT show the new subpixel rendering you just enabled.  but it does show up where it matters: in the browser.

2) Mac users may not see this problem and be aware of it because the Mac type engine handles OpenType PS files differently.  hopefully this will help them out.

bottom line, if you're going to be converting to EOT, start with a TrueType font.  as great as OpenType PS is for layout & print, it explodes the brain when used for web layout.

hope this is useful to the community.

WR!